# How do selectpicker values post ajax with other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a project that doesn't work. I don't selectpicker values right posting. Because I don't know JavaScript or insufficient information. My problem I can't use it with the same class separator selectpicker multi select.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker(
    {
        
        liveSearch:true,
        actionsBox: true,
        //deselectAllText:"Temizle",
        //selectAllText:"Tümünü seç",
        
    });
    
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
    
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('mobile');
}



    
});

</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        
        
        var action = 'fetch_data';

        var ms1 = get_filter('ms1');    
        var ms0 = get_filter('ms0');
        var ms2 = get_filter('ms2');
        
        
        
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, ms1:ms1, ms0:ms0, ms2:ms2},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        
        $('option:selected').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });

        return filter;
    }

    $('.selectpicker').change(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    
});
</script>
```

```html
<!-- index.php -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Multi Selected Selectpicker</title>

 
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://entellig.com/ornek/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://entellig.com/ornek/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://entellig.com/ornek/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://entellig.com/ornek/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    
    
    <div class="container">
  
            
    
            
<select class="selectpicker ms1"  multiple data-style="btn-success" data-selected-text-format="count" title="MS 1 ">

            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
            


<select class="selectpicker ms0" multiple data-style="btn-success" data-selected-text-format="count" title="MS 0">

            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>

</select>           
            
            
<select class="selectpicker ms2" multiple data-style="btn-success" data-selected-text-format="count" title="MS 2">

            <option value="Alex">Alex</option>
            <option value="Brade">Brade</option>
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Floyd">Floyd</option>
            <option value="Taylor">Taylor</option>

</select>               
            
    <div class="row filter_data">

                </div>      
            
                 
</div>

            
                
    
    
<style>
#loading
{
    text-align:center; 
    background: url('loader.gif') no-repeat center; 
    height: 150px;
}
</style>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker(
    {
        
        liveSearch:true,
        actionsBox: true,
        //deselectAllText:"Temizle",
        //selectAllText:"Tümünü seç",
        
    });
    
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('deselectAll');
    
    if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('mobile');
}



    
});

</script>



<script>
$(document).ready(function(){


    filter_data();

    function filter_data()
    {
        $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
        
        
        var action = 'fetch_data';

        var ms1 = get_filter('ms1');    
        var ms0 = get_filter('ms0');
        var ms2 = get_filter('ms2');
        
        
        
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{action:action, ms1:ms1, ms0:ms0, ms2:ms2},
            success:function(data){
                $('.filter_data').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function get_filter(class_name)
    {
        var filter = [];
        
        $('option:selected').each(function(){
            filter.push($(this).val());
        });

        return filter;
    }

    $('.selectpicker').change(function(){
        filter_data();
    });

    
});
</script>







</body>

</html>





<!-- fetch_data.php -->

<?php

    
    
if(isset($_POST["ms1"]))
    {
        $ms1_filter = implode("','", $_POST["ms1"]);
        
        echo '(There is MS1): '.$ms1_filter.'</br>';
        
    }
    

if(isset($_POST["ms0"]))
    {
        $ms0_filter = implode("','", $_POST["ms0"]);
        
        echo '(There is MS0): '.$ms0_filter.'</br>';
        
    }   
    

if(isset($_POST["ms2"]))
    {
        $ms2_filter = implode("','", $_POST["ms2"]);
        
        echo '(There is MS2): '.$ms2_filter.'</br>';
        
    }



?>
```

Problem row `$('option:selected').each(function(){`
or `$('.'+class_name+'option:selected').each(function(){`

if according to the selected should be / may be result view:

(There is MS1): 'A','C','D'...
(There is MS0): '2','4','5'...
(There is MS2): 'Floyd','Taylor,'Brade'..

[Here is the example that works incorrectly](http://entellig.com/ornek)

Comment: add a space $('.'+class_name+' option:selected').each(function()   or use "select[class='"'+class_name+'"] option:selected')

Comment: Selam-ın Aleykum Ahmed.. Allah bless you. Because 3 day I just struggled for only space. :) Thank you very much.Thank you thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.'+class_name+' option:selected').each(function(){
```

TRUE. THANK'S AHMED

Comment: vote up just for your greetings.  You are welcome. :)